# Trying to build simple python docker container

Tags: dockerfile

Im trying to make a docker container run this python script I made. Every time I run the container, I get an error of it not being able to find the script even though it is in that listed directory.
python: can't open file '/home/johnb/manual_into_ckl.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10
ADD manual_into_ckl.py .
WORKDIR /home/johnb
RUN pip install pandas 
CMD [ "python", "manual_into_ckl.py"]
```

Very new to this, not sure what else to do. Thanks

Changed the workdir, changed permissions, all still the same error.

Comment: You need to set the `WORKDIR` before you `ADD` (or `COPY`) a file into `.`, the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidMaze commented, you need to set the working directory *before* copying the file. I also suggest using `COPY` instead of `ADD` ([it is preferred](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy)).

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /home/johnb
RUN pip install pandas
COPY manual_into_ckl.py .
CMD [ "python", "manual_into_ckl.py"]
```